# Integration architecture

Tags: java, architecture, integration, soa

I'm developing server-side for mobile movie booking application. Server application should have common API to 2 existing booking systems in cinemas. In the future addition of new booking systems is possible. I don't like writing spaghetti-code, so application must be component (module) oriented. I'm looking at SOA and Mule ESB, but I have no experience with it. Whether correctly I have chosen a way? May be there are more than one (not ESB/not Mule) good solutions for my task.

PS: Common API must be HTTP/REST. API of booking systems are binary custom tcp protocol and SOAP service.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOA is fine, but an ESB seems overkill for something like this. For integrating with various booking services a simple [gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html) should suffice.

Comment: @opedge: Gateway is a simple enough pattern that one can implement from scratch. All you need is (1)a java interface (2)an implementation class per booking system and (3) a factory or a router that has conditional logic for using the right implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use Mule ESB with content based routing. That is based on the content of the booking your ESB knows which booking service to send it to. Then adding new booking services can be done by adding new routing rules.

See: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/integration-patterns-content-based-routing/

Comment: Mule ESB is a complicated environment, I have no experience at all in ESB :( May be you could advice some useful study materials?